# Android 11 File.listFiles on /dev/vendor/log returns null, while works fine on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, logging

here is kotlin code:

```
val folder = File("/data/vendor/log")
val files = folder.listFiles() ?: return
```

It works well on Android 10, but files get null value on Android 11, I had checked /data/vendor/log on Android 11, it is absolutely not null, had 7 directories at least, can anyone help this?

Comment: Use folder.exists() and folder.canRead() before you try to list.

Comment: And please get the error/typo from your post.